# Simple Device Driver Issue : cat: /dev/chardev: No such device or address

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am trying to learn Device Drivers and tried to compile a code, but I get the below error messages. I would appreciate if you give me pointers to resolve this issue
cat: /dev/chardev: No such device or address

Below are the logs:
@ubuntu:~/Desktop/C_code$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
chardev                12767  0

@ubuntu:~/Desktop/C_code$ ls -l /dev

crw-rw-rw-  1 root root     77,   0 2011-10-03 20:47 chardev

~/Desktop/C_code$ uname -r

2.6.38-8-generic

I am using the code from the following site "http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html"

Answer (score 0):

Try: `cat ~/Desktop/C_code/dev/chardev`. That file isn't necessarily in `/dev` yet, but you could copy it there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the device file is indeed present in the /dev. There was a typo in my logs . Sorry for that

rahulgade@ubuntu:~/Desktop/C_code$ ls -l /dev
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root     77,   0 2011-10-03 20:47 chardev

Answer (score 0):

the problem is basically that the major and minor number represented by the device node /dev/chardev don't represent a device. put in your source code a printk of the major and minor number just after the'ye assignment.

check if the numbers in the kernel log match 77 0 as the device node declare.
if not, delete the device node, and write the following command

```
sudo mknod /dev/chardev c <MAJOR> <MINOR>
```

of course the major and minor are the ones you printed to the kernel log.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html`, here
`chardev` is created in current working directory.
So you should cat `chardev` in your current directory not in `/dev/`. 
Or create `chardev` in `/dev/` directory instead.